# Не запускается systemd сервис после рестарта машины

Tags: linux, systemd

У меня есть демон процесс с таким service-файлом:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Zookeeper server (Kafka)
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/kafka
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/vagrant/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/home/vagrant/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

После ребута вижу статус loaded. Как сделать, что сервис стартовал автоматически?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В терминал:

```
sudo systemctl enable service_name
```

при запуске системы сервис включится автоматически.